# routes are not rendering results

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to figure out why my routes have stopped working.  I recently upgraded to Ember JS RC 3 (from RC2) and after going through the changelog, I can't figure out why my routes stopped working.  Maybe I changed something in trying to fix it; I don't know.  But here's what I've got.

Here are my routes.

```
App.Router.map(function() {

  this.route("site", { path: "/" });
  this.route("about");
  this.resource('posts', { path: '/posts' }, function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', { path: '/:post_id' });
    this.route('edit', { path: '/:post_id/edit'})
  });
  this.route("map");
});
```

Here is my route handler...

```
App.PostsIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Post.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

Here is my model

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  headline: DS.attr('string'),
  creator: DS.attr('string'),
  created: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Here's the JSON being pulled over the network (I see it coming, just not being rendered -- the view is not rendered at all)

```
[
  {
    "creatorID": "512808071f7152f9b6000001",
    "creator": "Aaron",
    "headline": "second entry",
    "body": "this is my second entry.  ",
    "updated": "2013-03-04T20:10:14.566Z",
    "created": "2013-03-04T20:10:14.566Z",
    "id": "5134ffa6095e930000000001"
  },
  {
    "body": "this is my first entry. ",
    "created": "2013-02-28T22:39:32.001Z",
    "creator": "Aaron",
    "creatorID": "512808071f7152f9b6000001",
    "headline": "first entry",
    "updated": "2013-03-01T18:13:35.934Z",
    "id": "512fdca479d3420000000001"
  }
]
```

Probably also important to note that I do NOT see any JS errors here, as I'm visiting localhost/posts

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:  Here is the template I'm using to render the entries (jade based).

```
div {{content}}
{{#each post in content}}
div(class="post limit-width")
    h3(class="headline") {{#linkTo 'posts.show' post}} {{ post.headline }} {{/linkTo}}
    p {{{post.body}}}
    h6
        em Posted by {{post.creator}} on {{post.created}}
{{/each}}
```

note that the {{content}} tag is being used to determine if there's even an object present; there is, but its length seems to be zero.  Which makes me think that no entries are being loaded via Ember Data, but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: can you show your templates? Maybe your error occurs in redering the template, and unluckily errors occurring in the templates are not shown.

Comment: There you go.  Let me know if you want to see more; happy to post

Comment: Your JSON seems to be missing root names. Not sure if this is your actual issue, but the API does expect (something like) that to identify the correct model. What happens if you include a root name, along the lines of: {post: [{"bla" : "bla"}, {"bla" : "bla2"}]}

Comment: I bet you are right harn145. Good eye!  So many variables here.

Comment: ham145 -- you are right.  That was the problem.  Thanks for your help.